# if i am using C2DM should i register always when sending data ?

Tags: android, push-notification, sendmessage, android-c2dm

When using C2DM, a device sending data to another device via server 
should they both register again and again whenever data transfer is required??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The client device only needs to register initially, and then if for any reason the registration ID is expired by the server a new one should be received.

So once you have a registration ID, you don't need to keep requesting new ones. In fact doing so is a very bad idea as you'll keep changing your reg ID, so keeping your own server knowing which is current becomes more difficult. Of course if your server tries sending the message to an old registration ID, the message will not arrive.

Comment: If my answer does what you need, then please vote it up, and mark it as the accepted answer. If you do that your Accept Rate will stay high, and people are more likely to answer your questions in future